# Python file isn't running, and shows this error: repl process died unexpectedly

Tags: python

```
days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']
sub_weights = {
  'chem': 5,
  'phy': 5,
  'math': 5,
  'spanish': 4,
  'eco': 4,
  'cs': 2,
  'eng': 2
  }

ilists = []

for x in sub_weights:
  for sub_weight in sub_weights:
    while sub_weight != x:
      i = [sub_weight, x]
      ilists.append(i)
print(ilists)
```

I wanted two counters to go together and explore two subject possibilities that I could go over together, so I assigned them weights.
I tried running it on sublime, vs code, replete, but received no errors even, it just wouldn't compile and would make my computer really slow.
I wrote the while loop because I didn't want to repeat one subject twice.
I think that's it, but I'm still not able to crack it.

Comment: Why do you have a while-loop inside the inner for-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while sub_weight != x` is an infinite loop - the loop's body doesn't change neither `sub_weight` nor `x`, so it loops indefinitely adding elements to `ilists` until the process consumes too much memory and is killed. It seems like you meant to use an `if` condition:

```py
for x in sub_weights:
  for sub_weight in sub_weights:
    if sub_weight != x: # Here!
      i = [sub_weight, x]
      ilists.append(i)
```

**EDIT:**
A more "pythonic" way of achieving this would be to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and then filter out the pairs of identical items in a list comprehension:

```py
from itertools import product
ilists = [p for p in product(sub_weights, repeat = 2) if p[0] != p[1]]
print(len(ilists))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not that familiar with itertools...where do you think a good place to start would be

Comment: @Thorb the official docs (linked in my answer)